# dynamic visualforce input field data-required text box for a radio field

Tags: visualforce, lightning, dynamic

I have a visualforce page in with lightning styling and want to fix an issue in it. 
There is a radio button that I need to conditionally make required.So when 
New is chosen the input field should be required and when existing is chosen input field for existing should be required.

```
<fieldset class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
    <span class="slds-radio" style="display: inline;">
        <input type="radio" id="NewX" name="nX" value="New" checked="checked"/>
        <label class="slds-radio__label" for="NewX">
            <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">New X</span>
        </label>
    </span>
    <span class="slds-radio" style="display: inline;">
        <input type="radio" id="ExistingX" name="eX" value="Existing" />
        <label class="slds-radio__label" for="ExistingX"> 
            <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">Existing X</span>
        </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

```
<div id="newX" class="slds-form__row slds-m-top_small">
<div class="slds-form__item" role="listitem">
    <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_stacked slds-is-editing">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input id="NewXName" type="text" data-required="true" class="slds-input" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Enter New X Name..." value=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="existingX" class="slds-form__row slds-m-top_small" style="display: none;">
<div class="slds-form__item" role="listitem">
    <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_stacked slds-is-editing">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <c:Typeahead_Updated searchBoxId="XSearchBox" ObjectApiName="X__c" primaryField="Name" searchScope="NAME" minSearchLength="3" recordLimit="10" 
               styleClass="slds-input" placeholder="Search For Existing X..." 
               destinationForSelectedId="xId" stealFocus="false" />
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="xId"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

any ideas on it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check which radio button is checked using document.getElementById('NewX').checked and then add or remove required attribute from input field, on click of submit button when saving the form. 
For Example :

```
if(document.getElementById('NewX').checked){
   document.getElementById('NewXName').required = true;
   document.getElementById('XSearchBox').removeAttribute('required');
}else 
if(document.getElementById('ExistingX').checked){
  document.getElementById('NewXName').removeAttribute('required');
  document.getElementById('XSearchBox').required = true;
}
```

Note : Not sure what is the ID of Existing field, i am using XSearchBox here. You should replace this with the id of existinginput field